# column functions in jooq to split strings

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am using jooq.  I have a field in the database that contains long strings. I want to apply string functions to the returned values from a select statement so that the values are returned in a labeled column. Here is an example:

```sql
select STAT_NAME, STAT_COUNT, AVERAGE, HALF_WIDTH, SIM_RUN_ID_FK
FROM ACROSS_REP_STAT
where STAT_NAME like '%:Queue%'
ORDER BY STAT_NAME, SIM_RUN_ID_FK;
```

In the above query, STAT_NAME is a really long string. Suppose I want to extract a substring of the returned string as a column:

```sql
select SUBSTRING(STAT_NAME, 1, 4) AS Something, STAT_NAME, STAT_COUNT, 
  AVERAGE, HALF_WIDTH, SIM_RUN_ID_FK
FROM ACROSS_REP_STAT
where STAT_NAME like '%:Queue%'
ORDER BY STAT_NAME, SIM_RUN_ID_FK;
```

How do I build a jooq statement for something like this?

Suppose that I wanted to use the position() function from the DSL to make the index, e.g. 4 in the substring() function variable.  The position() function returns a Field. I am having trouble getting something like this:

```
substring(STAT_NAME, 1, position(STAT_NAME, ":"))
```

to work because substring() expects an int not a Field

---

I see now that I am calling substring() with an int and a Field and that there is not method signature for this, but there is one for

substring(Field field, Field startingPosition, Field length)

How do I turn starting at 1 to a Field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [org.jooq.impl.DSL](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html) class contains all the functions that you need. In your case, [`DSL.substring()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#substring-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-). Typically, you will just static import all methods from that class

```java
import org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

and use the functions like in SQL

```java
ctx.select(substring(ACROSS_REP_STAT.STAT_NAME, 1, 4).as("Something"), ...)
   .from(...)
   ...
```

Or, given your updated question:

```
ctx.select(substring(
        ACROSS_REP_STAT.STAT_NAME, 
        inline(1), 
        position(ACROSS_REP_STAT.STAT_NAME, ":")).as("Something"), ...)
   .from(...)
   ...
```

Comment: This was helpful.  I have updated my question because I now see the reason that I was struggling with this.

Comment: @ManuelRossetti: I have updated my answer. There's no overload of `DSL.substring()` allowing for mixing `int` and `Field<? extends Number>` arguments. You'll have to wrap your `int` argument in a `Field<Integer>`